# What template to render Hash in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashmap, mustache

Using the Mustache template implementation for javascript How should template be for rendering Hash object. More and more examples deal with well known keys and values but how does one create template (knowing that hash is of form `<string,string>`)

```
var hash = {
    "Key1":"Value1",
    "Key2":"Value2",
    "Key3":"Value3",
    "Key4":"Value4"
};
```

`Mustache.render(hash,"{{WHAT COMES HERE}}");`

I am trying to output this

`<ul>
//for each object in hash
<li><a href="{{key}}">value</a></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mustache, its:

```
Mustache.render(html, data);
```

For repeating values, you can use sections

```
var html = '<ul>{{#list}}<li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>{{/list}}</ul>';
```

and the data:

```
var data = {
    list : [ //list is an array of items
        {key:'foo1',value:'bar1'},
        {key:'foo2',value:'bar2'},
        {key:'foo3',value:'bar3'},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: so from your answer if i got 100Keys then i need template to reflect that , man jstemplates makes life harder for trivial things

Comment: please view my question, i have included actual output requirement. Seems you already updated the answer

Comment: @Deeptechtons you can use sections. they repeat a section of HTML depending on the data passed on to it.

Comment: seems converting object to List is my only way out. another hour in the drain thanks joseph for the help

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from their documentation http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html it should be something like but arguments are the other way around.

"{{Key1}}, {{Key2}}, {{Key3}}...."